# I am seeing something strange running the w command and need help understanding it

Tags: bash, security

So I was checking around the server after a while of not looking on it and ran the `w` command:

```
 01:10:46 up 11 days,  2:53,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.05, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     tty1     -                Tue21    2days  0.74s  0.60s -bash
root     pts/0    86.x.xxx.xx      22:18    0.00s  0.28s  0.00s w
```

I should be the only one on the server, and had no clue what this `tty1` was or is doing so I ran `ps -aef --forest | grep bash` and found this one in particular

```
root         617       1  0 Aug01 tty1     00:00:00 /bin/login -p --
```

When I ran a `kill -9 617` and checked `w` it had gone:

```
 01:11:18 up 11 days,  2:54,  1 user,  load average: 0.12, 0.07, 0.06
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    86.x.xxx.xx      22:18    5.00s  0.29s  0.00s w
```

What is that? I Googled what `/bin/login -p --` was but only got information about the `--`. How was there a root logged in?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 with Docker and Docker Compose installed, that is all that runs on it @guiverc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about @Terdons answer, and for future viewers, I found the `TTY` is the screen it is attached to when in `PTS/<number>` and in my case, I was using my providers browser KVM which is `tty1` (no screen, stay alive), and the issue was killing the browser did not kill the KVM connection internally on the server.

If ran `watch w` and logged back into the root server via my KVM (internal access doesn't require the RSA key) I saw:

```
 15:51:54 up 12 days, 17:34,  2 users,  load average: 0.04, 0.05, 0.08
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     tty1     -                15:47    4:33   0.20s  0.07s -bash
root     pts/0    xxxxxxxxxx      15:38    4:49   0.26s  0.00s watch w
```

Bingo. If no `FROM` address is stated (`-`), it is a physical login from the server.

To kill it I did:

```
$ ps -aef --forest | grep tty1

root     2355734       1  0 Aug13 tty1     00:00:00 /bin/login -p --
root     2687566 2355734  0 15:47 tty1     00:00:00  \_ -bash
root     2688963 2686083  0 15:54 pts/0    00:00:00          \_ grep --color=auto tty1

$ kill -9 2355734
$ w

 15:55:00 up 12 days, 17:37,  1 user,  load average: 0.03, 0.03, 0.06
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    xxxxxxxxx      15:38    4.00s  0.08s  0.01s w
```

Answer (score 1):

One worrying possibility is that someone logged in as root. I can reproduce something very similar on my machine. First, I enabled root ssh access by adding this to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

And then restarted the `sshd` service:

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

And logged in as root (note that I have enabled the root account on this machine, have you done the same?):

```
ssh root@localhost
```

Now, when I run `w`, I see:

```
$ w
 17:06:36 up 3 min,  2 users,  load average: 1.98, 0.97, 0.38
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
terdon   :0        17:04   ?xdm?  29.31s  0.01s /usr/lib/gdm-x-s
root     pts/3     17:06   24.00s  0.00s  0.00s -bash
```

At the very least, you cannot rule out the possibility that an attacker gained access to your system. The only solution, in that case, is to restore from a backup or reinstall from scratch. If someone did get root access, there is simply no way of being sure they haven't done something bad otherwise.

Comment: Would it effect if I only have RSA keys for login and not password? Also, when I login via ssh I see `pts/<number>` too. But I saw `-` instead

Comment: @Jaquarh I don't really know. I am not an expert on security at all. All I can tell you is that by doing what I described above an logging in as root, I saw something very similar.

Comment: So, I've not seen it since I killed it and I'm recently wondering if it could of been my `KVM` that never actually killed its connection - I might try reproduce using my KVM

Comment: @Jaquarh yes, please don't take my answer as any kind of authoritative proof that your machine was compromised. All I can say is that it _could_ be _one_ explanation. I don't have the knowledge to say for sure, and you know what the machine was doing.

Comment: ok yeah! this is infact the cause, I logged in via my OVH panel and used the KVM -- after logging in I see `root     tty1     -                15:47   42.00s  0.20s  0.07s -bash` I now close out the browser and it stays active - I guess the KVM never closes its login connection for some reason in OVH hosted servers. Your post helped me see this thanks!

Comment: ah, great news! Could you please post that as an answer and accept it, so that the next person with a similar problem can see it?

Comment: Sure, but I'll keep my upvote on yours because your explanation helped me see it! Thanks Terdon!